# Не объявляется Runnable,в чём ошибка?

Tags: java, android

```
public class game extends Activity {
ImageButton imageButton5;
TextView textView3;
TextView textView4;
TextView textview5;
Timer timer;
Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    textview5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    imageButton5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable tadada = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Random rand = new Random();
            final int pS = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
            final int cS = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
            textView3.setText("Ваш результат:" + pS);
            textView4.setText("Результат компьютера:" + cS);
            if (pS < cS) {
                textview5.setText("Победил компьютер!Повезёт в следующий раз!");
            } else {
                textview5.setText("Вы выиграли!Поздравляю!");
            }
            if (pS == cS) {
                textview5.setText("Победила дружба;)");

            }
        }
    };
}







public void onClick(View v) {
    timer = new Timer();
    imageButton5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    imageButton5.setEnabled(false);
    handler.postDelayed(tadada, 2000);

}
```

tadada не объявляется,в чём дело?

Comment: Какую конкретно ошибку выдаёт?

Comment: Что значит не объявляется? в какой строке ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Наверно потому что у Вас Handler null =)

```
Handler handler;
```

Comment: Да, Handler handler объявлен и глобально и локально.